# Laptop ignores critical battery action

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, battery, hibernate, power-management

I am having an interesting problem with my Lenovo IdeaPad Flex14 laptop. To give a brief of setup: I am running Windows 8.1 Update 1 64-bit on Intel Core-i5 4200U with Intel's built-in GPU.

My problem basically consists of the laptop ignoring the critical battery action and depleting the battery, essentially running out of power.

I have set the 'Critical battery level' at 5% with 7% reserve and the 'Critical battery action' is 'Hibernate'. However, if I close the lid, the laptop will go to sleep and stay in sleep indefinitely until the battery runs out.

Now, I could have experimented a bit with this and tried some settings variations, but the problem is I am using BitLocker and every time something like this happens, I have to go through system recovery. Not only that, but low voltages are very bad news for any system, as they do not trigger protection circuits immediately.

My hope is that someone else has experienced this and knows what have caused it, so hopefully I can fix it without too much hassle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many different power profiles that are choices in the drop down for power configuration. Change all of these power profiles to reflect what you want to happen at these times. It's weird I know but I have had many different Windows systems that do not follow the selected power plan.